# Clear cart after order using Magento SOAP API

Tags: magento-1.9

I have created API for order place in Magento but the issue is when I place my order then cart will not get empty and the products still appear in the cart. How can I clear my cart?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `shoppingCartProductRemove (SOAP V2)`

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'); 

$sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey'); 

$result = $proxy->shoppingCartProductRemove($sessionId, 10, array(array(
'product_id' => '4',
'sku' => 'simple_product',
'qty' => '1',
'options' => null,
'bundle_option' => null,
'bundle_option_qty' => null,
'links' => null
)));   


var_dump($result);
```

For more details please refer : [**Product Remove**](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/checkout/cartProduct/cart_product.remove.html)

Comment: But this is for simple product and I have only configurable product also How can i pass all products in cart to remove.